# How to resolve GlusterFS peer rejected when after reboot system?

Tags: centos, glusterfs

How to resolve GlusterFS peer rejected, when after Reboot system and without delete other file In /var/lib/glusterd, delete everything except glusterd.info (the UUID file) ?

**OS:** CentOS 7